# Run OpenGL on AWS GPU instances with CentOS

Tags: opengl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, gpu

I need to execute some off-screen rendering program on AWS EC2 GPU instance with CentOS. However, while I found that Ubuntu is very easy to setup, I cannot let CentOS work properly.

The goal is to run some essential utility/test tool on EC2 GPU instance (without screen or X client). In the following article, I will describe how the Ubuntu can be setup and how CentOS/Amazon Linux AMI fails.

### Ubuntu

On ubuntu 12.04, everything works very smoothly. The EC2 environment I used are:

- Instance type: Both CG1 and G2 were tested and worked properly.
- AMI image: Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS for HVM Instances (ami-b93264d0 in US-East)
- Most of the other settings are default.

After the instance is launched, the following commands are executed:

```
# Install the Nvidia driver
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
# Driver installation needs reboot
sudo reboot now

# Install and configure X window with virtual screen
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=None --virtual=1280x1024
sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &

# OpenGL programs are now workable. Ex. glxinfo, glxgears
DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo
```

The `glxgears` can also run in the background without physical screen or X client:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 glxgears
95297 frames in 5.0 seconds = 19059.236 FPS
95559 frames in 5.0 seconds = 19111.727 FPS
94173 frames in 5.0 seconds = 18834.510 FPS
```

### CentOS or Amazon Linux AMI

Both "CentOS" and "Amazon Linux AMI" are derived from Red Hat Enterprise edition. However, I cannot make any of them work.

A few days ago, AWS [announced their new G2 instance type](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/build-3d-streaming-applications-with-ec2s-new-g2-instance-type.html). In this article, the [Amazon Linux AMI with NVIDIA Drivers](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FYCDDTE) is recommended for Linux platform. In this AMI, the Nvidia driver, X window and OpenGL libraries are all installed. However, I just get GLX error messages when trying to execute OpenGL programs.

The EC2 instance is launched with the following setting:

- AMI image: Amazon Linux AMI with NVIDIA GRID GPU Driver (ami-637c220a in US-East)
- Instance type: G2
- Most of the other settings are default

After booted, the steps to reproduce this issue is very simple:

```
sudo X :0 & # Start the X window
glxinfo
glxgears
```

The output is:

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

$ glxgears
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

The following error is found in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[139017.484] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

I have googled and tried a lot of possible solution, such as:

- Use the clean CentOS HVM AMI and install Nvidia driver manually
- Tried both CG1/G2 instance types
- Regenerate the X window config with nvidia-xconfig
- Use Xvfb instead of X window
- Reinstall Nvidia driver after mesa libraries are installed

... but none of them works.

Does anyone have a concrete solution for this issue? Everything I mentioned should be reproducible (I tried many times). I'll appreciate if you can provide reproducible instructions to make OpenGL (GLX) works on EC2 GPU instances with CentOS/Amazon Linux AMI.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://github.com/rncry/gpu-desktop

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`lspci | grep VGA`

You should see the `busID` is `0:3:0`.

Using sudo, add this into your xorg.conf like so:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GRID K520"
    BusID           "0:3:0"
EndSection
```

This should fix GLX failures.

Comment: It works like a charm. AmazonLinuxAMI and CentOS need to specify `BusID` explicitly, but Ubuntu doesn't need. Not sure about it root cause.

Comment: Incredible. Works very well on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel 3.5.0-45-generic, which runs on amazon ec2 g2.2xlarge gpu instance.

Comment: To configure xorg - use this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/where-is-the-xorg-conf-file-located-under-unix-linux-bsd/

Comment: If I wanted to do this on a p2.xlarge server instead how much would I have to change?

Comment: This also works in Ubuntu 16.04 with g3.4xl instances.

Answer (score 6):

Just an additional find:

I did this to get the X Server running:

```
sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &
```

However, my OpenGL application was still not using the GPU for image rendering, and was therefore being REALLY slow.

This is what saved me -- setting a DISPLAY environment variable to the same display (ID: 0) that the X Server is using:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```